# WinError 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,

Tags: python, django

[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

faced error , email verification for user registration in Django

it tried some solution and not worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.